# Call to snprintf and vsnprintf inside a variadic function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use variadic functions inside a variadic function. I check many examples on Internet and Stack Overflow but I can't find my mistake.

When I'm running my program using Visual Studio, I have an access violation when it's calling snprintf.

Here the header:

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdarg>
class Console
{
   public:
     static void writeLine(const char *s, ...);

   private:
     Console() = delete;
    ~Console() = delete;
};
```

The class:

```
#include "Console.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

void Console::writeLine(const char *s...)
{
    va_list arg1, arg2;

    // Search the total length
    va_start(arg1, s);
    va_copy(arg2, arg1);
    int length = snprintf(nullptr, 0, s, arg1);
    va_end(arg1);

    size_t size = length + 1;
    char *szBuff = new char[size]; // note +1 for terminating null byte

    // Format the string
    vsnprintf(szBuff, size, s, arg2);
    va_end(arg2);

    std::cout << (const char*)szBuff << std::endl;

   delete(szBuff);
}
```

And the main program:

```
#include "Console.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   Console::writeLine("Example with an int (%d) and a string(%s)", 10, "my string");
}
```

I'm sure I did a stupidity, but I can't see why it's not working.

**EDIT**

The cout call is just un example, I'm using a function from Windows to write to the console of Visual Studio. It's why, I'm doing this class: to format the data before to write the result to the console.

Comment: Since the shown code writes to `std::cout`, which is fully capable of formatted output, what exactly is accomplished by trying to reimplement a prehistoric wheel called "stdio" using prehistoric C-style variadic parameters? `std::cout << "Example with an int (" << 10 << ") and a string(" << "my string" << ")" << std::endl`. I see nothing that this `writeLine()` function does that's actually needed, and is not available directly in `std::ostream`. P.S.: `snprintf` doesn't know anything about `va_alist`, hence your crash.

Comment: Shouldn't your call to `snprintf` actually be to `vsnprintf`?  `snprintf` is prototyped as `int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...)` -- it doesn't accept an argument of type `va_list` as its last parameter.

Comment: The code is clearly using C++11 or later, so you using use a C++-style variadic template instead of a C-style variadic function.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the printf family is more powerful than std::cout. However how C++ is way better than C, when something in C works better than C++ we will still use it.

Comment: Sure, @MichaelChourdakis, printf is way more powerful. It's so much easier to end up with buffer overflows and undefined behavior with type-unsafe printf(), and friends, as exemplified in this very question, then with a type-safe `<<` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong function to calculate the size of your buffer.  `snprintf()` does not take a `va_list` as input. Also, Microsoft's implementation of `vsnprintf()` is not defined as accepting a NULL buffer as input, like `snprintf()` does. You need to use `_vscprintf()` instead:

> `_vscprintf` returns the number of characters that would be generated if the string pointed to by the list of arguments was printed or sent to a file or buffer using the specified formatting codes. The value returned does not include the terminating null character.

Also, you are not freeing your buffer correctly. Since you use `new[]` to allocate it, you need to use `delete[]` to free it.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void Console::writeLine(const char *s, ...)
{
    va_list arg1, arg2;

    va_start(arg1, s);

    // Search the total length
    va_copy(arg2, arg1);
    size_t size = _vscprintf(s, arg2) + 1; // note +1 for terminating null byte
    va_end(arg2);

    char *szBuff = new char[size];

    // Format the string
    vsnprintf(szBuff, size, s, arg1);

    va_end(arg1);

    std::cout << szBuff << std::endl;

    delete[] szBuff;
}
```